# hadoop master node slave node datanode

Tags: hadoop, nodes, master-slave

if a master node goes down what happens to the cluster? Can any slave node act as a master? Does it need any additional configuration?

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817391/hadoop-datanode-namenode-secondary-namenode-job-tracker-and-task-tracker/7818812#7818812

Answer (score 2):

The NameNode and the JobTracker are single points of failure.

Comment: Namenode in hadoop is no longer a SPOF. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.3-alpha/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html

Answer (score 1):

If your Hadoop version 0.21 or higher. then you can configure checkpoint node for back up.
If your hadoop version is lesser then it then secondary namenode is there for it.

You can create back up note instead for master failure. Back up node,checkpoint node hardware configuration should be same as namenode.

Enjoy hadooping :)